# why input field not display full width in android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am using `react-native` .My input field is not display on full `width` why ? But when I check on IOS it works correctly display input field on full width .
here is my code
https://rnplay.org/apps/aHRkHA

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  registerComponent,
} from 'react-native-playground';
import {
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
           <View style={styles.container}>

                <Text style={styles.heading}> Login</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.loginInput}
                    placeholder="Type here to translate!"
                />
            </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#EF501E',
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    logo: {
        width: 50,
        height: 50
    },
    heading: {
        fontSize: 30,
        marginTop: 20
    },
    loginInput: {
        height: 50,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#33090C',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
});

registerComponent(App);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overriding the `alignItems: 'center'` of the parent with `alignSelf: 'stretch'` for `<TextInput>`:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  ...

  <View style={{alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.loginInput}
      placeholder="Type here to translate!"
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not use RN Playground. Can you update yourself?